# How to show a loader via HOC?

Tags: reactjs

I want to use a HOC component to display a loading animation. Some components have the prop "isLoading" and others "isPending". How can I give the HOC a defauult prop, that will make it show the loader?

```
isLoading
isPending
isNotReady
...

  const WithLoader = ControlledComponent => ({ isPending, ...props }) => {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Higher order component WithLoader like below:

```js
export const WithLoader = ControlledComponent => ({
  isLoading, isPending, isNotReady, children,
}) => ((isLoading || isPending || isNotReady) ? <Loader />
  : <>{children}</>
);
```

And then reuse it like:

```js
<WithLoader>
  <YourComponent />
</WithLoader>
```

Or

```js
<WithLoader>
  <YourComponent1 />
  <YourComponent2/>
</WithLoader>
```

This way, you can create a generic higher order loader component which can be used even for multiple sibling components.

**P.S.** In the above implementation example of WithLoader, `<>{..}</>` used are react fragments, assuming that you don't want to have any additional markup in the DOM. If you want an html container for styling purposes, you can make it a `<div>` tag instead of a React.Fragment(<>).

Answer (score 1):

This should work. 
Assuming your loading component name is `Loading`

```
const WithLoader = ControlledComponent => ({ isLoading, isPending, isNotReady, ...props }) => { 
  return (isPending || isLoading || isNotReady) ? 
  <Loading /> 
  : 
  <ControlledComponent {...props} />;
}
```